# Function not returning converted type of variable

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have an assignment and have created a function called `cycle_convert(variable, n)` that converts the type of a `variable` based upon the number of step sizes `n`. I have the following fixed order of types in Python:
int → float → bool → string → complex

For example I have the variable `number = 10` and with my function `cycle_convert(number, 2)` it would change the type from a `int` to a `bool`. It also works for wrapping round and negative step sizes.

I have code that completes these tasks but when returning the variable, even though the function converts it, the converted type does not seem to return and variable `number` is still an `int`. My code is as follows:

```
def cycle_convert(x, n=1):
    if type(x) == int:
        num = 1
    elif type(x) == float:
        num = 2
    elif type(x) == bool:
        num = 3
    elif type(x) == str:
        num = 4
    elif type(x) == complex:
        num = 5
    prev_type = type(x)

    final_num = num + n
    while final_num not in range(1,6):
        if final_num <1:
            final_num = 5 + final_num
        if final_num >5:
            final_num = final_num - 5

    if final_num == 1:
        x = int(x)
    elif final_num == 2:
        x = float(x)
    elif final_num == 3:
        x = bool(x)
    elif final_num == 4:
        x = str(x)
    elif final_num == 5:
        x = complex(x)
    print('Your variable type has been changed from ', prev_type, 'to ', type(x), ': ')
    return x


number = 10
cycle_convert(number, 2)
```

Can anyone explain to me why the return function does not work in this instance?

Thanks

Comment: You are starting the function with `if type(x) == int:`. `x` is not defined it (it's in the memory from previous version)

Comment: If the function takes input `p` why are you using `x` in your functions?

Comment: As above, and I would suggest looking at [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: worked perfectly fine for me with some change : indent your instruction inside function definition, change `p` to `x`

Comment: Indeed they are correct in my code and it runs fine, however the type of number in my console is still `int`.

Comment: have you tried invoking it like `number = cycle_convert(number, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a typo I believe. You are defining your function to take an argument `p` and `n`, with `n`'s default value = 1. But later, in your fuction, you are evaluating a variable `x` which means the `p` passed whenever the function is called will never take effect. This should work:

```
def cycle_convert(x, n=1):
    if type(x) == int:
        num = 1
    elif type(x) == float:
        num = 2
    elif type(x) == bool:
        num = 3
    elif type(x) == str:
        num = 4
    elif type(x) == complex:
        num = 5
    prev_type = type(x)

    final_num = num + n
    while final_num not in range(1,6):
        if final_num <1:
            final_num = 5 + final_num
        if final_num >5:
            final_num = final_num - 5

    if final_num == 1:
        x = int(x)
    elif final_num == 2:
        x = float(x)
    elif final_num == 3:
        x = bool(x)
    elif final_num == 4:
        x = str(x)
    elif final_num == 5:
        x = complex(x)
    print('Your variable type has been changed from ', prev_type, 'to ', type(x), ': ')
    return x


number = 10
cycle_convert(number, 2)
```

Output:

```
Your variable type has been changed from  <class 'int'> to  <class 'bool'> :
```

Comment: Apologies, that was just a typo, it is actually x in  the code. It works, however the type of number in the console is still `int`

Comment: That's a lot of copied code just to change the header of the function.

Comment: @geds133 I just run this on command line and there hasn't been any issue. Yes. You are returning `x`, don't expect `number`'s type to get updated. If that's what you want, it's a different issue to address. Let me know and I'll edit my answer so that `number`'s type gets updated according to the function you are using.

Answer (score 0):

With the changes above and adding result of your function to `number`you got the correct changed type.

```py
def cycle_convert(x, n=1):
    if type(x) == int:
        num = 1
    elif type(x) == float:
        num = 2
    elif type(x) == bool:
        num = 3
    elif type(x) == str:
        num = 4
    elif type(x) == complex:
        num = 5
    prev_type = type(x)

    final_num = num + n
    while final_num not in range(1,6):
        if final_num <1:
            final_num = 5 + final_num
        if final_num >5:
            final_num = final_num - 5

    if final_num == 1:
        x = int(x)
    elif final_num == 2:
        x = float(x)
    elif final_num == 3:
        x = bool(x)
    elif final_num == 4:
        x = str(x)
    elif final_num == 5:
        x = complex(x)
    print('Your variable type has been changed from ', prev_type, 'to ', type(x), ': ')
    return x

number = 10
number = cycle_convert(number, 2) #change here
```

Comment: Apologies I must have been getting confused about what the return function does here. When I invoke it as `number = cycle_convert(number, 2)` it overwrites the variable but should the return not overwrite this?

Comment: No. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986339/8080758) for further explanation

Comment: I see, then it is fine, my code was correct I had misunderstood the return function